# SharedPreferences is not saving data

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save a string in a key "password". I intend to save the data when the app is closed. So I tried to put the data & save it in onStop() method. But it's not working.

```
protected void onStop() {

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "gmail.nextgenancestor.knocked", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.edit().putString("password", password);
    prefs.edit().commit();

    Log.d("password", password);
    Log.d("goodbye", prefs.getString("password", "not found"));

    super.onStop();


}
```

Result from the log:

password: EMERGENCY

goodbye: not found

Comment: Put this code in the `onPause()` method instead of `onStop`

Comment: @kabuto178, that's not solving the issue. Getting the same output from log.

Comment: Ahhhh, did you create an `Editor` object for the preferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `prefs.edit()` creates an instance of [`Editor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) that you must re-use when you commit.  This should fix the code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
        "gmail.nextgenancestor.knocked", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("password", password);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are setting data in an instance of the `SharedPreferences.Editor` which you didn't call `commit()` on it . try this :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("gmail.nextgenancestor.knocked", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putString("password", password).commit();
```

or :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("gmail.nextgenancestor.knocked", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("password", password);
editor.commit();
```

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/54/android-shared-preferences-tutorial/) about how to use `SharedPreferences` in Android

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
            "gmail.nextgenancestor.knocked", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.edit().putString("password", password);
    prefs.edit().commit();
```

with

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                "com.example.dsfsdf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.clear();
edit.putString("password", password);
edit.commit();
```